# libpng error : Invalid IHDR data (Stitching 3 Images)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch 3 images side by side.

The tree structure for my directory is

```
.
├── image_stitching_simple.py
├── images
│   ├── fig_1.jpg
│   ├── fig_2.jpg
│   └── fig_3.jpg
└── output.png
```

The python script is:

```
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", type=str, required=True, help="path to input directory of images to stitch")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, required=True, help="path to the output image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["images"])))
images = []


for imagePath in imagePaths:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    images.append(image)


print("[INFO] stitching images...")
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher() if imutils.is_cv3() else cv2.Stitcher_create()
(status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch(images)


cv2.imwrite(args["output"], stitched)

cv2.imshow("Stitched", stitched)
```

I am using the following line to run my script

```
python image_stitching_simple.py --images images/ --output output.png
```

The error I am getting is

```
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_stitching_simple.py", line 44, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Stitched", stitched)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/9523d527-1b9e-48e0-7ed0-a36adde286f0/volume/opencv-suite_1535558719691/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

I tried the following methods to try to remove the error:

1. I resized the images again (using cv2.resize command) to the dimensions of original image but it didn't help.
2. I tried to put the images in the parent directory but it didn't help.
3. I tried to find the dimensions of image by using shape. The dimension is (4000,3000,3)
4. I used the matplotlib.pyplot to plot the image, the image is rendered in pyplot with finite dimensions but stitcher is not able to get the dimensions.
5. I tried google to search IHDR dimensions but I can't find what it is.

I request you to please clarify some of my doubts

1. What is IHDR dimensions and how it is different from real dimensions of image?
2. Is there any preprocessing required to perform on the images.

P.S I used a tutorial website [PyImage Search](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/17/image-stitching-with-opencv-and-python/#download-the-codehttps://) for this code. The image given by this website is able to run on the same script without any changes to the script.
(
This gave me intuition that there must be some pre-processing required to stitch the image.
I tried google but didn't find any relevant source for the same.
)

I am very sorry the images are large, so I am providing google drive link to the images folder. Pardon me for any inconvenience caused.
[Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sDQOXRij_TGtIuU0FcFE7lqUNKG1V0Db?usp=sharing)

EDITS :

1. I used `print(imagePath)` to check if the script is loading the correct files.

The output is

```
[INFO] loading images...
images/fig_1.jpg
images/fig_2.jpg
images/fig_3.jpg
```

It seems that script is loading the correct files.

2. I used the `file images/fig_1.jpg` to find the type of file.

The output is

```
images/fig_1.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=12, height=3000, manufacturer=samsung, model=SM-M307F, orientation=upper-right, xresolution=210, yresolution=218, resolutionunit=2, software=M307FXXU3BTG1, datetime=2020:08:03 08:13:17, width=4000], baseline, precision 8, 4000x3000, frames 3
```

The file is a JPEG, I don't really know how it will affect. Please explain.

Thank You.

Comment: What about the input images?

Comment: Something's gone very wrong. You appear to be using `libpng` (which is for PNG format images) to read JPEG images! Try printing `imagePath` before each `cv2.imread()` to check what files you are opening. Failing that, try running `file images/fig_1.jpg` to see if you have renamed a PNG as a JPEG or somesuch.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Please look for the edits section for the mentioned changes you asked for. It will be a great help from your side if can tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: I am fairly sure that your installation of OpenCV is broken. It should not be using `libpng` to read JPEG images. I would suggest you remove and reinstall OpenCV.

Comment: @MarkSetchell 
Sir, I think that's not the case, with another set of the images (JPG images only), the same script is giving no errors. If you want I can add the link of those images too. I think the problem is with these images but I am not able to find what.

Comment: You can try stripping the EXIF data and metadata from the images with `exiftool`, i.e. `exiftool -all= IMAGE.JPG` and see if that works. Or you can have **ImageMagick** read and re-write the images with `magick INPUT.JPG -strip OUTPUT.JPG` and see if OpenCV likes the images any better after that - or if either tool gets upset by your images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell tried both methods, neither worked. Same error.